# Inline content for colorbox not being displayed

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps, jquery-plugins, google-maps-api-3

i'm trying to display the google map into colorbox popup window by clicking a link that pulls the map from a hidden div. i'm using the `inner html` concept of colorbox http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example1/ for loading the map from a hidden div `<div id="map_canvas"></div>` into it's window.

The whole blocks of code is are following

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="colorbox.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../colorbox/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=xyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyx&sensor=false"></script>
```

```
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function initialize() 
{
    var cenLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(/////////,///////////);
    var myOptions = {
                       zoom: 15,
                       center: cenLatlng,
                       mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                    }

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),myOptions);

    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(/////////,////////////);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                          position: myLatlng,
                                          map: map,
                                          title:"XXXXXXXXXXX"
                                       });

    var contentString =  '<div class="info"><img style="float:left;padding-right:10px;" src="/dummy.jpg"><b>YYYYYYYY</b> <br/>' +

             'ZZZZZZZZZZ <br />' +

             'AAAAAAAAA <br />' + 

             'Telephone: BBBBBBBBB</div>';

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                                                  content: contentString,
                                                  width:150,
                                                  height:90
                                               });

    infowindow.open(map,marker);

    // Start of newly added code block
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                                    infowindow.open(map,marker);
                                         });
    // End of newly added code block
}
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

```
    <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".inline").colorbox({
                                  inline:true,  
                                  scroll:false


                                  });

        });
    </script>
```

---

```
 <div id="map_canvas" style=width:700px; height:500px; display:none;></div>
```

---

```
<p><a class='inline' href="#map_canvas">Display map in colorbox</a></p>
```

the problem is that the the map isn't displayed at all when it is loaded from the hidden div. On the other hand the map is loaded perfectly both into the hidden div and colorbox window when the div `map_canvas` isn't hidden.

i shall have to use all the blocks of code for my application but the map should be loaded properly from the hidden div.

Any idea?

By the way, i'm using google api v-3

Answer (score 1):

When using inline content, you don't want the target content (the element to which the `href` refers) to be hidden.  Instead, enclose the content (unhidden) in a another div that is hidden like this:

```
<div style="display:none">
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width:700px; height:500px"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, i tried this technique too but `ie` can't render the map properly. The following style of wrapping div `<div style="visibility:hidden">` serves the purpose partially. Thanks,

Comment: Well that's a different issue entirely than what you described in the question above.  IE is sometimes funny about things in an absolutely positioned element.  Depending on whats "not working", you might want to try adding this css rule: `#cboxWrapper div:first-child { position:relative }` either in your colorbox css file or after the file in the `head` of your document. A relative wrapper in an absolute element fixes some IE issues.  This might adversely affect other colorbox windows, so you could alternatively set that div to `relative` programatically in the onLoad callback.

Comment: `ie` displays the first screen shot of the map properly this way as usual but it can't display the map properly when it is dragged to the nearby location. Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you'll need to initialize your map on the onComplete of the colorbox.

```
    $(".inline").colorbox({
                          inline:true,  
                          scroll:false
                          onComplete: function(){
                              initialize();
                          }

                          });
```

and remove this line in your script:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

But your map will be reloaded everytime you open colorbox

Comment: you suggestion doesn't do anything. the map won't load at all if i remove the line google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize); even when the div isn't hidden. i'm using it on the contrary of body on load event. it's all about loading the map into hidden div.